# My android app stops as soon as I open it?

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, apk, android-manifest

The app is a simple login screen which thendisplays the logged in students attendance marks.....although it never opens, just says unfortunatly this has stopped and i can work out why! Can anyone help work out why?

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.ac.qub.qubattend"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="uk.ac.qub.qubattend.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="uk.ac.qub.qubattend.StudentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_student" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:text="Student Number"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_student.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StudentActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:text="Attendance"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/att"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Student class

```
 package uk.ac.qub.Student;

    public class Student {
    private String StudentId;
    private String password;
    private String week1;
    private String week2;
    private String week3;
    private String week4;
    private String week5;
    private String week6;
    private String week7;
    private String week8;
    private String week9;
    private String week10;
    private String week11;
    private String week12;

    public Student(){

    }
    public Student(String StudentId, String password, String week1,
            String week2, String week3, String week4, String week5,
            String week6, String week7, String week8, String week9,
            String week10, String week11, String week12) {
        this.StudentId = StudentId;
        this.password = StudentId;
        this.week1 = week1;
        this.week1 = week2;
        this.week1 = week3;
        this.week1 = week4;
        this.week1 = week5;
        this.week1 = week6;
        this.week1 = week7;
        this.week1 = week8;
        this.week1 = week9;
        this.week1 = week10;
        this.week1 = week11;
        this.week1 = week12;

    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return StudentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        StudentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getWeek1() {
        return week1;
    }
    public void setWeek1(String week1) {
        this.week1 = week1;
    }
    public String getWeek2() {
        return week2;
    }
    public void setWeek2(String week2) {
        this.week2 = week2;
    }
    public String getWeek3() {
        return week3;
    }
    public void setWeek3(String week3) {
        this.week3 = week3;
    }
    public String getWeek4() {
        return week4;
    }
    public void setWeek4(String week4) {
        this.week4 = week4;
    }
    public String getWeek5() {
        return week5;
    }
    public void setWeek5(String week5) {
        this.week5 = week5;
    }
    public String getWeek6() {
        return week6;
    }
    public void setWeek6(String week6) {
        this.week6 = week6;
    }
    public String getWeek7() {
        return week7;
    }
    public void setWeek7(String week7) {
        this.week7 = week7;
    }
    public String getWeek8() {
        return week8;
    }
    public void setWeek8(String week8) {
        this.week8 = week8;
    }
    public String getWeek9() {
        return week9;
    }
    public void setWeek9(String week9) {
        this.week9 = week9;
    }
    public String getWeek10() {
        return week10;
    }
    public void setWeek10(String week10) {
        this.week10 = week10;
    }
    public String getWeek11() {
        return week11;
    }
    public void setWeek11(String week11) {
        this.week11 = week11;
    }
    public String getWeek12() {
        return week12;
    }
    public void setWeek12(String week12) {
        this.week12 = week12;
    }



    }
```

Main Activity

```
package uk.ac.qub.qubattend;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import uk.ac.qub.DBConnection.DBHelper;
import uk.ac.qub.Student.Student;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText username;
EditText password;
TextView loginerror;
Button login;
ArrayList<Student> studentList;
static ArrayList<Student> currentStudent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    studentList = (ArrayList<Student>)db.getAllStudents();

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    loginerror = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String uname = username.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        for(Student s : studentList){
            if(s.getStudentId().equals(uname) && s.getPassword().equals(pass)){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, StudentActivity.class);
            currentStudent.add(s);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            loginerror.setText("Invalid Login Details");
            username.setText("");
            password.setText("");
        }

        break;}

    default:
        break;
    }


}

}
```

StudentActivity class

```
package uk.ac.qub.qubattend;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import uk.ac.qub.Student.Student;
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StudentActivity extends Activity {

TextView attendance;
ArrayList<Student> cstudent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student);
    attendance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.att);
    cstudent = (ArrayList<Student>) MainActivity.currentStudent;
    for (Student s : cstudent) {
        attendance.setText(s.getWeek1() + "\n" + s.getWeek2() + "\n"
                + s.getWeek3() + "\n" + s.getWeek4() + "\n" + s.getWeek5()
                + "\n" + s.getWeek6() + "\n" + s.getWeek7() + "\n"
                + s.getWeek8() + "\n" + s.getWeek9() + "\n" + s.getWeek10()
                + "\n" + s.getWeek11() + "\n" + s.getWeek12());
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.student, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

DBHelper class

```
package uk.ac.qub.DBConnection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import uk.ac.qub.Student.Student;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "QUBAttendanceDB";
// tasks table name
private static final String TABLE_StudentInfo = "studentinfo";
// Table Columns names
// id column
private static final String KEY_ID = "StudentId";
// question column
private static final String KEY_PASS = "question";
// answer column
private static final String KEY_WEEK1 = "Week1";
private static final String KEY_WEEK2 = "Week2";
private static final String KEY_WEEK3 = "Week3";
private static final String KEY_WEEK4 = "Week4";
private static final String KEY_WEEK5 = "Week5";
private static final String KEY_WEEK6 = "Week6";
private static final String KEY_WEEK7 = "Week7";
private static final String KEY_WEEK8 = "Week8";
private static final String KEY_WEEK9 = "Week9";
private static final String KEY_WEEK10 = "Week10";
private static final String KEY_WEEK11 = "Week11";
private static final String KEY_WEEK12 = "Week12";

// Database constant
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

/**
 * Method to check the db name and version
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase = db;
    // Create Table method
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_StudentInfo + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " TEXT" + KEY_PASS + " TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK1
            + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK2 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK3 + "TEXT, "
            + KEY_WEEK4 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK5 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK6
            + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK7 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK8 + "TEXT, "
            + KEY_WEEK9 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK10 + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK11
            + "TEXT, " + KEY_WEEK12 + "TEXT, " + ")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    // implementing add questions method
    addAttendance();

}

/**
 * Add Questions Method using Question Object with question, 4 options and
 * correct answer
 */
private void addAttendance() {
    Student s1 = new Student("40023798", "letmeinhere", "90", "80", "0",
            "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0");
    this.addStudent(s1);

}

// Checking that existing database table called TABLE_QUEST is dropped
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_StudentInfo);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * method for adding a new question into the database
 * 
 * @param quest
 */
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, student.getStudentId());
    values.put(KEY_PASS, student.getPassword());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK1, student.getWeek1());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK2, student.getWeek2());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK3, student.getWeek3());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK4, student.getWeek4());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK5, student.getWeek5());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK6, student.getWeek6());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK7, student.getWeek7());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK8, student.getWeek8());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK9, student.getWeek9());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK10, student.getWeek10());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK11, student.getWeek11());
    values.put(KEY_WEEK12, student.getWeek12());
    // Inserting Row with question
    dbase.insert(TABLE_StudentInfo, null, values);
}

/**
 * Method to move questions in database to an ArrayList
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_StudentInfo;
    dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setStudentId(cursor.getString(0));
            student.setPassword(cursor.getString(1));
            student.setWeek1(cursor.getString(2));
            student.setWeek2(cursor.getString(3));
            student.setWeek3(cursor.getString(4));
            student.setWeek4(cursor.getString(5));
            student.setWeek5(cursor.getString(6));
            student.setWeek6(cursor.getString(7));
            student.setWeek7(cursor.getString(8));
            student.setWeek8(cursor.getString(9));
            student.setWeek9(cursor.getString(10));
            student.setWeek10(cursor.getString(11));
            student.setWeek11(cursor.getString(12));
            student.setWeek12(cursor.getString(13));
            studentList.add(student);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return question list
    return studentList;
}

/**
 * Method to Check Database number of rows
 * 
 * @return
 */
public int rowcount() {
    int row = 0;
    // select all query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_StudentInfo;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row = cursor.getCount();
    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: provide  logcat for the same

Comment: no one's gonna look in your whole code.Just post the logcat and point out the line no. at which the error is coming.

Comment: you posted the whole code. its better you cut down the post to relevant parts and do post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

you should have checked `logcat` to see what exception.

I guess it's a simply NullPointerError on initial part. you can trace it from dump log,initial that variable before use it.

Comment: if use eclipse Windows->ShowView->Android->LogCat,or use `adb logcat` at terminal

Comment: theres nothing in the log file relating to any code errors that I can see....other projects simialr are working but this one wont...the apk installs too quickly on my phone, like takes a second instead of a few

Comment: just open logcat, then run your app to make it crash. CTRL+Z to stop it when you get enough infos, then search your package name like com.xxxxx.xxxxx., also check any `Exception` like `java.lang.IllegalState` and `java.lang.NullPointerException`.it should be a VM shut down when your app exit unexpected.